# Firefox - Java Platform plugin does not exist in the plugins

Tags: firefox, windows-10, java, firefox-extensions, plugins

I have just installed the latest version of `Java (1.80_60)` on a fresh installed `Windows 10`. `Java` is not recognized by `Firefox` (which is up to date - version `41.0.1`) despite it is installed properly. When I go to `Plugins` settings, I am not able to see `Java(TM) Platform` plugin.

So, what is the proper way of **enabling Java plugin on Firefox**?

*p.s. I'm using **64 bit** Java on **64 bit** Windows 10.*

Answer (score 0):

32-bit versions of Firefox do not support 64 bit Java, and 64 bit versions of Firefox do not support any plugins except for Flash.  So the answer is that there is no way to do this.  This is a general trend: browsers are losing support for plugins, and new browsers do not include plugin support.

You should not enable Java in the browser, as it is insecure.  If you do need to use the Java plugin for e.g. work, banking, or tax purposes, run it from a throwaway user account with limited privileges.